# How to post new Json Structure On Update

Tags: python, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that gets the updates from firebase database. Its functioning well as its updating within the REST methology, however, I am unable to save the recent values before the changes.

I tried looping over everything, but it was just a mess
I ve got an idea to screenshot the whole thing and then save it somewhere after it updates then psot it to the bottomest. But yeah, it's not  a good practice. I'm really new at json and python syncs so I'm not really sure of what should I do. Do you have any suggestions?

Here's my **code** by the way:

```
@app.route("/room1")
def room1():



#USE THIS LATER
#%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p
result1date = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/', None)

for key in result1date.keys():
    key = sorted(result1date.keys())[-2]
    currentdate = key

    print currentdate

result1 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/' + currentdate + '/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/', None)
result2 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/' + currentdate + '/Inspection/Scan-out/Inspector/', None)
print result1


print currentdate

for key in result1.keys():
   inspector = key
timeout = result2[inspector]["Time"]

# for key in result1date.keys():
#    Date = key

result1datetime = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/'+ currentdate +'/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/'+ inspector +'/', None)





for key in result1datetime.keys():
    key = sorted(result1datetime.keys())[-2]
    time = key
    print time



print time

ch1 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Entrance louver clean and dust-free"]
# ch2 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Room plate number – clean and well-polished"]
ch3 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Appearance door surface- in good condition"]
# ch4 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Let the door close by itself to test the door closure – in working order"]
ch5 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Eye viewer and fire escape plan in order"]
ch6 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Privacy Sign or Make Up Room Sign"]
# ch7 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Key card holder – in working order"]
ch8 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Switches at the entrance working correctly"]



return render_template('new.html', ch1=ch1,ch3=ch3,ch5=ch5,ch6=ch6,ch8=ch8, inspector=inspector, date=currentdate, time=time, timeout=timeout, timedif = timedif)
```

Here's my **html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Room 1</h1>
      <h1>Scan-in: 
      {{date}} </h1>


  <h2>Time: {{time}}</h2>
  <h2>Time-out: {{timeout}}</h2>
  <h2>Inspection time: {{timedif}}</h2>


  <h1>Inspector: {{inspector}} </h1>
   <h1>Checklist: </h1>
   <h4> Entrance louver –clean and dust-free: {{ch1}} </h4>
   <h4> Room plate no. – clean and well-polished: {{ch2}} </h4>
   <h4> Appearance door surface- in good condition: {{ch3}} </h4>
   <h4> Let the door close by itself to test the door closure – in working order: {{ch4}} </h4>
   <h4> Eye viewer and fire escape plan in order: {{ch5}} </h4>
   <h4> Privacy Sign/Make Up Room Sign: {{ch6}} </h4>
   <h4> Key card holder – in working order: {{ch7}} </h4>
   <h4> Switches at the entrance working correctly: {{ch8}} </h4>

  <h2><a href = "\">Go back to home page</a></h2>
```

<

I tried looping those, and I got a tabular form. which I really don't want to have.

I want it to post everytime the values change let's say

FIRST UPDATE

...update happens

SECOND UPDATE

FIRST UPDATE

and not by tabular form. or another idea is to save everything in one data and then pass it as `rows=rows` and then loop through it?